# Create a dataframe based on column values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as 20000 X 50. Two of the columns are Date and Time (represented as hour). Remaining columns have observations of some parameters during the time. What I am trying to achieve is create a new dataframe which averages all the remaining column values for every 3 hours per day and creates a an ID columns for this which can be numbers from 1 to 8. Each representing 3 hour range.
I have enclosed an image of the source and what should be result. Any help is very much appreciated.
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZONnZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column `Date` and column `Hour` created by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) by `1` and [`floordiv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.floordiv.html) with [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) with aggregate `mean`:

```
df['Hour'] = df['Hour'].sub(1).floordiv(3).add(1)
df = df.groupby(['Date', 'Hour'], as_index=False).mean()
print (df)
         Date  Hour      col1      col2      col3
0  05/01/2018     1  5.333333  5.333333  7.666667
1  05/01/2018     2  6.000000  6.000000  4.000000
2  06/01/2018     1  4.000000  6.333333  7.000000
3  06/01/2018     3  6.000000  6.000000  3.666667
```

Detail:

```
print (df['Hour'].sub(1).floordiv(3).add(1))
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    3
8    3
9    3
Name: Hour, dtype: int64
```